# How to navigate to one component to another by passing parameters

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, aura-attribute, aura-iteration

I'm new to Salesforce. I have just started with lightning Aura components. I want to understand simple workflow of aura. Can anyone help me with the code for below requirement. Thanks in advance.

Requirement.
I have two custom components. One component has list of custom object records. Another component has detail page of that record. Onclick of record in the first component it should navigate to second component by passing Id and display current record details.

Sample code attached;
Component1.cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"><aura:attribute name="Result" type="String"/>
  <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
  <ui:inputText aura:id="n1" maxlength="5" size="5" label="Number1" required="true"/>
  <ui:inputText aura:id="n2" maxlength="5" size="5" label="Number2" required="true"/>
  <ui:button label="Sum" press="{!c.Calculate}"/></aura:component>
```

Component1.js

```
({Calculate : function(component, event, helper) {
  var a = component.find("n1").get("v.value");
  var b = component.find("n2").get("v.value");
  var res = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
  res = res + '';
  component.find("navService").navigate({    
    "type": "standard__component",
     "attributes": {
         "componentName": "c__Component2"    
     },    
     "state": {
         "res":"5"  
     }
});
```

}
})

Component2.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable"><aura:attribute name="res" type="String" />The result is {!v.res}</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lighting:navigation for that:

cmp:

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
```

JS: (for standard record page)

```
goToRecord: function(component,event,helper) {
    component.find("navService").navigate({
        "type": "standard__recordPage",
       "attributes": {
           "recordId": "001xx000003DGg0AAG",
           "objectApiName": "TargetObjectAPIName__c",
           "actionName": "view"
       }
    });
}
```

Js for custom component (should implement `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface)

```
goToRecord: function(component,event,helper) {
    component.find("navService").navigate({    
        "type": "standard__component",
         "attributes": {
             "componentName": "c__MyLightningComponent"    
         },    
         "state": {
             "c__recordId": ""//pass the target target record id    
         }
    });
}
```

References:

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm
2. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation

---

**CORRECTIONS:**

correct state as below:

```
"state": {
     "c__res":"5"  
 }
```

Component2 html:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" >
    <aura:attribute name="res" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
    Hello {!v.firstname}.

    The result is {!v.res}
</aura:component>
```

Now its JS:

```
({
    onPageReferenceChange: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        var firstname = myPageRef.state.c__res;
        cmp.set("v.res", res);
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't want to navigate to standard page. I want to navigate to another custom component

Comment: added in answer

Comment: I tried the above solution. But its not working.I have attached the sample code. Can you please check and help me in finding bug.

Comment: You are passing the param in url but you are not handling in comp2. Added the code needed in answer

Comment: I changed the code as per your correction. But still its not working. I'm trying this by calling component1 in lightning application. Is it right way?

Comment: It should be in lightnig experiance. That is, you should be able to see standard lightnig header, tabs etc in top